# How can I obtain the given highlighted text information from this key-value pair

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, wikipedia-api

I am trying to obtain Career Total Goals & Appearances of football players using the Wikipedia API. I have been able to find access to the given information, though I am unsure what to do with the format that it is presented in.

For now, I am just trying to console log the information.

```
function fetchResults(searchQuery) {
    const endpoint = `https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?origin=*&action=parse&format=json&prop=sections&page=Jamie_Vardy&section=15&prop=wikitext`;
    console.log(endpoint);
    fetch(endpoint)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data.parse.wikitext);

    })
    .catch(() => console.log("ERROR"));

}
```

I have highlighted the piece of information I wish to obtain in the image below:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That seems to be a part of text that is part of a string under the `*` key in `wikitext`.

The proper way to extract this would be to use some kind of JS implementation of a parser to parse the Wikitext format and then go through the parse tree or token stream to find the thing you want.

A more hacky and fragile solution is to use a regular expression to try and match the text there. E.g. you might do something like `Career total\s(.+?)\}` and then parse the bit with numbers somehow.

Comment: Thank you, I will attempt through this method, however, I believe there might be other API's better suited for my needs.